# Apple ID button doesn't get localised for some languages

Tags: ios, swift, apple-id

I have come across a bizarre problem. The `SignIn with Apple ID` button has a very straight forward approach to be setup in Swift.  The same code works with English, German, Russian:

[image]

but doesn't work with French and Arabic.

[image]

```
extension MainViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate, ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
    func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return self.view.window!
    }
    
    func setUpSignInAppleButton() {
        self.loginOrRegisterStackView.removeAllSubviews(type: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton.self)
        let authorizationButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(authorizationButtonType: .default, authorizationButtonStyle: UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .white : .black)
        authorizationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAppleIdRequest), for: .touchUpInside)
        authorizationButton.cornerRadius = 15
        self.loginOrRegisterStackView.insertArrangedSubview(authorizationButton, at: 0)
    }
}
```

There is nothing extraordinary. The button gets instantiated and based on the selected language the correct language for `SignIn with Apple ID` should be shown. And yet, it doesn't work for Arabic and French.

What can I do, please?